# Was the "Gambler" god from "Lucifer" the same entity as the unnamed god from "American Gods"?

Tags: neil-gaiman, american-gods, lucifer

In the Lucifer comic series, Jill Presto used to be a vessel for Basanos, a living Tarot deck. Their relationship didn't end well, Basanos forcefully impregnated her against her will. She managed to "abort" one of the fetuses, but she founds that there is one more child inside her, one that wants to kill her. Oh, and the end of world is coming, since Yahweh quit the job and creation is unravelling.

Following the guide of a dying psychic, she goes to Las Vegas and bets all her considerable money on a LOSING number. Then she finds this interesting gentleman waiting outside for her commenting on her bet:
[image]

[image]

Since most gods usually like to introduce themselves by name, I find it very weird that we never know this "gambler" (as it was called by someone else) name. 
And there in "American Gods" we have very similar god living in LV, who never introduces himself and also seems to take a keen interest in gambling.

This might be a long shot, since the "Sandman-Lucifer" universe is not the same as the "American Gods" one, but I'm just curios, have Gaiman or Carey somehow copied from one another?

Comment: _Lucifer_ was written after _American Gods_; also keep in mind that people couldn't remember the god from _American Gods_, while Jill clearly remembers this one (of course one could make a case that she isn't strictly speaking ordinary, but then so isn't Shadow).

Comment: @Gallifreyan Gambler seems to be dissolving in further panels (ibb.co/kUotjF) which would make him hard to remember. Also Jill just gave him a huge offering, while Shadow hasn't even talked with him